# Dreamweaver CC not recognising html5 selectors

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

I'm not to sure whether I've asked this question in the right place. If not could you direct me to the correct outlet. Thanks. Anyway down to the question. I spent some time last night installing the new shiny Dreamweaver CC (Creative Cloud version) and all seemed to be going swimmingly, until; I found myself having trouble getting DW to recognize HTML5 Css Selectors.

I have a basic page as of current and I'm using the  and  tags. However when I try to apply styles to these elements, I get no response or change at all. both in DW design view and the browser (Firefox/Chrome).

I'm working from an external style sheet at present, and have built most of the document via hand code. I can see (div) elements in the selector pane to the right of my design view, and divs are receiving their styles. But the 'header' selectors, although hand coded into the Css document are not showing and are not being recognized by DW.

I have;

- Hand coded the elements.
- Checked doctype.
- Checked for spelling errors.
- Tried converting the HTML 5  tags to `<div id="header">` & Css from `header {} to #header {}` (Even this draws no change in the selector pane or the browser window.)

  ```
      <!--/ header /-->
      <header>

          <!--/ logo / heading /-->
          <div id="site-header">
              <section id="logo"><h1>title / logo</h1></section>
              <section id="heading"><h3>heading</h3></section>
          </div>

          <!--/ navigation /-->
          <div id="site-nav">  
            <ul id="nav">                      
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Achievements</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
            </ul>              
          </div>

      </header><!--/ << end header /-->

  <!--/ (css) heading /-->
  header {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
  }
  ```

Comment: I gave up on Dreamweaver a long time ago. It's so wonky. Best of luck.

Comment: @fauverism I like quite a few of it's features and it's functionality. It can be temperamental but if you work it right it can have its pro's. :)

Comment: Ditch DW, get a nice text editor, like SublimeText + LiveReload plugin and Emmet ;-)

Comment: If it's not even working in the Browser, then you probably have an issue - is the stylesheet actually loading, if you did `body { background #000; }` for example, does that show up?

Comment: @Nick R Yeah, I am getting responses from other styled elements on the page. just not the HTML 5 Elements.

Comment: Are you declaring the right DOCTYPE?

Comment: Even if you don't declare a doctype, not that you wouldn't -  they will still render as block level elements in Firefox and Chrome, so this one is a bit odd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after staring for hours at the code on here and in the document, it turns out I was using html comments in the css code. - << I'm such a moron. Thanks for the help guys.

`<!-->` does not work in css. changed the comments from, `<!-->` to `/*--*/`.